# Synchronize color categories in Outlook

Tags: colors, outlook, categories

We set up Outlook calendars in my company in a shared way.
This works correctly, we found the solution by going to modify each of the categories_list.xml files on each of the workstations.

However, one last problem is against us,
when a user (A) adds an appointment to his calendar, for example, and the latter invites another user (B) to this appointment, the appointment does appear for user A and B but for user B the category color does not apply.
Do you have a suggestion to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance ;)

[image]

Comment: Did you have a chance to check whether such categories exist on another machine?

Comment: Yes we have added the same categories on the pc

Answer (score 1):

Only category names are visible on items when you share folders on Exchange server; colors are per user. Other users will see your categories in a white color (unless it's already in their color category list).

When you open a shared mailbox, your permission level determines whether or not you can use and edit the category list. Read more about Outlook categories in the [Outlook Categories and Color Categories](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-categories-and-color-categories/) article.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I received a response from Microsoft support and indeed it is not possible to solve my problem : /